# Flutter textform field update data if changed ifelse update data based on intial value

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have a data update form in flutter.
I have created a text form field for required data wherein the intial value of each field is set to value already stored in the firestore.
My code is showing no errors and is updating data.
But if there is no need a edit a particular field i don not change it , then the field is being set to null
I need that to not change and be the same value as previous.
My code is as below.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        drawer: newdrawer(),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Edit Task'),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Title',
                    ),
                    initialValue: widget.postid.data['Title'],
                    onChanged: (value){
                      this.Title=value;
                    },

                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                  Container(
                    height: maxLines * 24.0,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      maxLines: maxLines,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Enter Summary',
                        contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 25.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                      ),
                      initialValue: widget.postid.data['Summary'],
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        this.Summary = value;
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                  SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Task to be given to',
                      contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 25.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                    ),
                    initialValue: widget.postid.data['Taskgivento'],
                    //TODO: use tagging system or search when typed system
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      this.Taskgivento = value;
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Status',
                      contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 25.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                    ),
                    initialValue: widget.postid.data['Status'],
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      this.Status = value;
                    },
                  ),
                  DateTimeField(
                    format: dateformat,
                    onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) {
                      return showDatePicker(
                          context: context,
                          firstDate: DateTime(1900),
                          initialDate: currentValue ?? DateTime.now(),
                          lastDate: DateTime(2100));
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Enter Date to be completed',
                      contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 25.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                    ),
                    initialValue: widget.postid.data['Completion'].toDate(),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      this.Completion = value;
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 25.0),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 90.0,
                    height: 50.0,
                    child: FlatButton(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      disabledColor: Colors.grey,
                      disabledTextColor: Colors.black,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                      child: Text('Update Task'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Firestore.instance.collection('Task').document(_postdocid()).updateData({
                          'Title': this.Title,
                          'Summary': this.Summary,
                          'Taskgivento': this.Taskgivento,
                          //'Status': 'Active',
                          'Completion': this.Completion,
                        });
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: *if there is no need a edit a particular field i don not change it , then the field is being set to null* are you retrieving the values if there is no edit?

Answer (score 0):

Assign values to Title, Summary and so on...

```
this.Title = widget.postid.data['Title'],
this.Summary = widget.postid.data['Summary'],

and so on ...
```

you are providing initial value on TextFormField to display and not on the variable you use later.
if you do not edit any TextForm Field then value of that variable is  =  null,

Comment: if it is not null , id i change the title then it wont change if i use the above

Comment: use setState on Onchange
```  
onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
       this.Summary = value;
      });
                      },
```

Comment: Still it is going to null if no changes are made